Plotting signals of different length as function of each other in python
I have logged some data using 2 different devices on the same hardware, and the log interval was not the same. Now I have 2 arrays of different length(13518 and 68462 samples long), but the start and endpoints of these are the same, so I want to plot them as a function of each other to find any correlation. However, I can't think of a way to change the length of an array, while keeping the general shape.
Lets say I have 2 arrays:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,3,5,7,9,4,2]
y = [3,8,16,5]

x1 = np.linspace(0,1,len(x))
x2 = np.linspace(0,1,len(y))

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x1,x)
plt.plot(x2,y)
plt.show()

The arrays clearly have correlation but can't be plotted as function of each other because of the size difference.

Oops you forget to attach the code! ... Assuming the graphical problems without proper code or reproducable is hard

Try scipy's interp1d to create an interpolation function and  shorter signal to match the length of the longer one
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 4, 2])
y = np.array([3, 8, 16, 5])

t1 = np.linspace(0, 1, len(x))
t2 = np.linspace(0, 1, len(y))

f_interp = interp1d(t2, y, kind='linear')

y_interp = f_interp(t1)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))

plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(t1, x, 'b-', label='Signal x')
plt.plot(t2, y, 'r-', label='Signal y')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.title('Original Signals')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)

plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(x, y_interp, 'g.-')
plt.xlabel('Signal x')
plt.ylabel('Interpolated Signal y')
plt.title('Correlation Plot')
plt.grid(True)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

correlation = np.corrcoef(x, y_interp)[0,1]
print(f"Correlation coefficient: {correlation:.3f}")


For your actual data
f_interp = interp1d(np.linspace(0, 1, 13518), shorter_signal, kind='linear')
interpolated_signal = f_interp(np.linspace(0, 1, 68462))


You are interested in upsampling of a signal. Given some sparse information of a signal you are trying to predict the missing samples in-between. There are many ways to go about that - simplest ones are using techniques like Nearest Neighbour, Linear, Quadratic, Cubic approximations, etc. You can read about all interpolation techniques here: Interpolation
Numpy offers a simple linear interpolation via:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,3,5,7,9,4,2]
y = [3,8,16,5]

x1 = np.linspace(0,1,len(x))
x2 = np.linspace(0,1,len(y))
y = np.interp(x1,x2,np.array(y)) # interpolate
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x1,x)
plt.plot(x1,y)
plt.show()

And if we take a look at what y looks like now:
[ 3. ,  5.5,  8. , 12. , 16. , 10.5,  5. ]

We can see the missing values are just the average of the two around them. If you had used a different interpolations technique results would be much different.
